# How to reduce redundant code using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

`dt.html` and `st.html` are exactly same only difference in controller is `scoket.on` call  `dtconsumer` vs `stconsumer` , How can i use one controller for both views or same view and controller for two different state. there is alot of redundant code in `js` and `html`. what is best approach to resolve this issue ?

Do i need to write directive ?

dt.html

```
<div class="panel-body display-logs" scroll-bottom="event" style="width:100%;">
                        <ul style="list-style: none;">
                            <li ng-repeat="message in event | limitTo:1000" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span>{{message.value}}</span></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
```

Ctrl-1.js

```
var searchEnv = 'DT';
$scope.event = [];
socket.on('dtConsumer',function (data) {
        var obj = {
            file:$scope.filename,
            data:data
        }
        var messageSize = getBytesForBuffer(data);
       $scope.event.push(data);
    });
```

Ctrl-2.js

```
var searchEnv = 'st';
$scope.event = [];
socket.on('StConsumer',function (data) {
        var obj = {
            file:$scope.filename,
            data:data
        }
       $scope.event.push(data);
        var messageSize = getBytesForBuffer(data);
    });
```

app.js

```
.state('app.dt', {
        url: '/dt',
        templateUrl: 'view/partials/dt.html',
        controller: 'DitCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.st',{
        url:'/st',
        templateUrl:'view/partials/st.html',
        controller:'StCtrl'
    })
```

Comment: If your question is "how can I use one controller for multiple templates", I wrote a little article on that a while back. You might be looking for the old "ng-include" which no longer exists. Go to www.tcoz.com/#/errata and take a look at "ng-include in Angular 2?"

Answer (score 1):

You could pass dt/st via `$stateParams`, so you could keep 1 url with dt/st as a parameter. Something like this.

app.js

```
.state('app.dt', {
    url: '/:type',
    templateUrl: 'view/partials/dt.html',
    controller: 'DitCtrl'
})
```

ctrl.js

```
var searchEnv = $stateParams.type;
$scope.event = [];
socket.on(searchEnv+'Consumer',function (data) {
    var obj = {
        file:$scope.filename,
        data:data
    }
    var messageSize = getBytesForBuffer(data);
   $scope.event.push(data);
});
```

Comment: can you give me an example how can i implement using $stateParams ?

Comment: so using your $stateParams approach  i dont need to have two views and two controllers

Comment: just have one controller that will retrieve data based url $stateParams

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how this works. You can set right socket listeners based on $stateParams.type. Also you have 2 files you need to update instead of 4 :). Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know what the limit is, but I hardly believe you would reach it. I guess the limit would be max URL length (if there is one). You can add multiple params, separating them with /, like this: url: '/:type/:param2/:param3/:param4....' and just read them using $stateParams in your controller.

Comment: but in my navbar i have different tabs `<href="app.dt>` and `<href='app.st`> that rendered different $states , do i need to rendered same `$state` `app.dt` for both tabs ?

Comment: @hussain use ui-sref="app.dt({type: 'dt'})",ui-sref="app.dt({type: 'st'})"  instead

Comment: that means we have to use separate html files for each states lik for `app.dt` we have to use dt.html and for `app.st` st.html , again we are using two views

Comment: i have implemented your code `var searchEnv = $stateParams.type;` i tried to print searchEnv and its not priniting anything

Comment: Please provide plunker of your code, I think problem is somewhere else :) @hussain